# gnuplot one odd xtic value display

Tags: gnuplot

I have created a gnu plot control file (.plt) with number of nodes 40 to 80 with gap of 10 and last value as 84. when I generate output I don't get value 84 shown in xtics. I want values from 40 to 80 as shown in figure and want to display 84 also. Here is my gnuplot control file

```
set terminal pngcairo size 640,480 
 set output 'test2.png' 
 set logscale y 2 
 set xlabel 'Number of Nodes'  
 set ylabel 'Average Number of Collisions' 
 set key left top 
 set xrange [36:92] 
 set grid xtics 
 set grid ytics 
 set xtics center offset 0,0 
 set tics font ', 12'  
 set font ', 12'  
plot '-'  title 'test2' pt 4 lc rgb 'black'  dt 4 with yerrorlines 
40 600.600000 440.2
50 1800.400000 488.4
60 3000.000000 1200.0
70 500.200000 370.0
80 400.600000 460.0
84 15600.000000 20000.0
e
```

and the output I get is like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `xtic()` on column 1 as an extra column in the data:

```
plot '-' using 1:2:3:xtic(1) title 'test2' pt 4 lc rgb 'black'  dt 4 with yerrorlines
```

[image]